# ddply : push or pull?

Tags: r, plyr

Does ddply push or pull when grouping data? 
I.e, does it involve many passes over the data frame, or just one?

Comment: I'd say it splits up the data, goes over every piece doing what it has to do, and puts it back together. You could always look at the source yourself (try `getAnywhere()`, you'll need it) or wait until hadley passes by.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the code, you see the general structure of the function:

```
function (.data, .variables, .fun = NULL, ..., .progress = "none", 
    .drop = TRUE, .parallel = FALSE) 
{
    .variables <- as.quoted(.variables)
    pieces <- splitter_d(.data, .variables, drop = .drop)
    ldply(.data = pieces, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress, 
        .parallel = .parallel)
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>
```

so it basically rearranges the variables in a format that's easier to use, then breaks the data into pieces, and then use ldply on those pieces. Those pieces are generated by the function splitter_d. Pieces is actually a little bit more sophisticated than a list - it's a pointer to the original data and a list of indices. Whenever you request a piece of the list, it looks up the matching indices and extracts the appropriate data. This avoids having multiple copies of the data floating around. You can see how that functions using `getAnywhere("splitter_d")` or `plyr:::splitter_d`.

ldply passes once over every piece of data. After that, it combines everything back into a dataframe. Actually, in the help files of ldply is written:

> All plyr functions use the same
>   split-apply-combine strategy: they
>   split the input into simpler pieces,
>   apply .fun to each piece, and then
>   combine the pieces into a single data
>   structure. This function splits lists
>   by elements and combines the result
>   into a data frame. If there are no
>   results, then this function will
>   return a data frame with zero rows and
>   columns (data.frame()).

I couldn't say it better myself. And miracle, the first sentence is to be found on the help page for ddply as well.

Comment: Pieces is actually a little bit more sophisticated than a list - it's a pointer to the original data and a list of _indices_. Whenever you request a piece of the list, it looks up the matching indices and extracts the appropriate data.  This avoids having multiple copies of the data floating around.

Comment: @Hadley: thx for the correction. I didn't really go through the whole source code. I'll adjust.